# Very slow outgoing requests, from **some** servers

Tags: http, ipv6

In this case, it's an HTTP request to `https://www.instagram.com/`, but it has happened before like this.

- From my home (Ubuntu, i686) server it's very fast (~ 0.3 sec).
- From my online, modern (Ubuntu, x86_64) server it's very slow (~3.5 sec).
- From another online, older (Redhat, x86_64) server it's in between (~ 0.6 sec).

All 3 servers are in the same country. They all run Linux, though not the exact same. Results are consistent.

`dig` from all 3 servers gives the same ipv4 result.

Why the difference? I'm not worried about the middle (0.6 sec), but 3.5 sec is waaay to slow.

I've had a similar problem with a very slow SSH handshake, which was due to ipv6 vs ipv4. Could that be the problem? How would I find out?

Comment: To determine if IPv4 vs IPv6 connectivity is a possible factor, determine which of these hosts connect using which protocol.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes, that makes sense. How? Their DNS is only set up for IPv4. Can it still be a 4 vs 6 problem?

Comment: You need to capture traffic from the network while you are testing. Without seeing the actual network traffic, it is practically impossible to debug such a problem.